# Android disable all cameras on a device with multiple cameras

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way to disable all the cameras on an android device? e.g. If I have a device with 3 cameras can I disable the first camera then the second...?

I tried the [device admin class](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) like this but it's deprecated

```
devicePolicyManager!!.setCameraDisabled(adminComponent, !isChecked)
```

I've been following this repo https://www.github.com/dkreider/android-disable-camera

Comment: Please can you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello thx for ur response. I tried the device admin class and disable the camera 
devicePolicyManager!!.setCameraDisabled(adminComponent, !isChecked)

i followed this repo https://github.com/dkreider/android-disable-camera

Comment: @JamesRiordan any idea please?